# NameError from input function

Tags: python

I want to make a program that asks your age then from there tells you whether you can drive or not. I want it to re-ask the question if the user inputs a letter or symbol instead of a number.

Input:

```
J
```

Error:

```
Python "Programs\welcome.py", line 3, in <module>
    age = str(input("How old are you?: "))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'J' is not defined
```

Code:

```
while True:
    age = str(input("How old are you?: "))
    if int(age) > 15 and age.isdigit:
        print ("Congradulations you can drive!")
    elif int(age) < 16 and age.isdigit:
        print ("Sorry you can not drive yet :(")
    else:
        print ("Enter a valid number")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be running Python 3 code in a Python 2 interpreter.

The difference is that in `input()` in Python 3 behaves like `raw_input()` in Python 2.

Furthermore, `age.isdigit` doesn't call the `isdigit()` function as you would expect.  Rather, it just confirms that the function exists.

Once you fix the `isdigit()` problem, you also have another bug: you're performing the `int(age)` conversion *before* ascertaining that it consists only of digits.

#### A Python 2 program

```
while True:
    age = raw_input("How old are you?: ")
    if age.isdigit() and int(age) > 15:
        print "Congradulations you can drive!"
    elif age.isdigit() and int(age) < 16:
        print "Sorry you can not drive yet :("
    else:
        print "Enter a valid number"
```

#### A Python 3 program

```
while True:
    age = input("How old are you?: ")
    if age.isdigit() and int(age) > 15:
        print ("Congradulations you can drive!")
    elif age.isdigit() and int(age) < 16:
        print ("Sorry you can not drive yet :(")
    else:
        print ("Enter a valid number")
```

Note that both of these implementations could be further improved by changing the conditionals, but that's beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

`input` will evaluate whatever string it receives, which isn't what you intended to happen.

Comment: input expect python syntax, where as raw_input takes everything as string